# Inserting formatted string with single quotes with Pypyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pypyodbc

I'm trying to insert a network path as a string value using Pypyodbc:

```
    def insert_new_result(self, low, medium, high, reportpath):
    reportpath = "'" + reportpath + "'"
    self.insertsql = (
        """INSERT INTO [dbo].[Results] ([low],[medium], [high], [date]) VALUES
        ({low},{medium},{high}, GETDATE(),{reportpath})"""
        .format(low=low, medium=medium, high=high, reportpath=reportpath))
    self.conection.cursor().execute(self.insertsql).commit()
```

This is evaluating to

```
'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Results] ([low],[medium], [high], [date]) VALUES
            (0,2,2, GETDATE(),\\'\\\\share\\dev-temp\\report_10b29ef6-7436-11e6-ab96-534e57000000.html\\')'
```

Notice the extra single quote at the start of the share path, causing an invalid sql error. I have tried a few things like .format(), building the string and escaping however it keeps including the single quote *after* the first \\.

How can I get self.insertsql to evaluate to

```
'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Results] 
     ([low],[medium], [high], [date]) 
 VALUES 
     (0,2,2, GETDATE(),'\\\\share\dev-temp\report_10b29ef6-7436-11e6-ab96-534e57000000.html\')'
```

Comment: It looks like the extra quote mark is being returned from your {reportpath} values in the output above. Then I think you need to escape it in the SQL string by using two lots of single quote marks. So in VALUES 
     (0,2,2, GETDATE(),''\\\\share\dev-temp\report_10b29ef6-7436-11e6-ab96-534e57000000.html\'')'

Comment: adding ''{reportpath}'' returns self.insertsql as
GETDATE(),\\'\\'\\'\\\\share\\dev-temp\\report_32636b92-7444-11e6-b9ae-534e57000000.html\\'\\'\\'

... removing reportpath = "'" + reportpath + "'" gives
GETDATE(),\\'\\'\\\\share\\dev-temp\\report_93d410de-7443-11e6-8c52-534e57000000.html\\'\\')'

Still not sure where this extra \\' is coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `string.format()` then you are creating *dynamic SQL* which leaves you open to all the indignities of *SQL injection*, like messing with string delimiting and escaping. You should simply use a *parameterized query*, something like this:

```python
self.insertsql = """\
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Results] ([low],[medium], [high], [date], [reportpath]) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, GETDATE(), ?)
"""
self.params = (low, medium, high, reportpath, )
self.conection.cursor().execute(self.insertsql, self.params).commit()
```

**edit re: comment**

As a simplified, self-contained test, the code

```python
conn = pypyodbc.connect(conn_str, autocommit=True)
crsr = conn.cursor()

sql = """\    
CREATE TABLE #Results 
    (
        id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
        reportpath NVARCHAR(255)
    )
"""
crsr.execute(sql)

# test data
reportpath = r"\\share\dev-temp\report_10b29ef6-7436-11e6-ab96-534e57000000.html"

sql = "INSERT INTO #Results (reportpath) VALUES (?)"
params = (reportpath, )
crsr.execute(sql, params)

crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM #Results")
row = crsr.fetchone()
print(row)
```

displays this

```
(1, u'\\\\share\\dev-temp\\report_10b29ef6-7436-11e6-ab96-534e57000000.html')
```

Comment: True, but the original problem still exists with this method.

Comment: @3lysium - I thought that the "original problem" was a SQL syntax error. Anyway, I have updated my answer with a working example.

Comment: Thanks, I also used reportpath = reportpath.encode('unicode-escape') on the string in Python 3